# GET http://localhost:8080/resources/css/index.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: java, html, css, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I know that there are similar questions on this subject, but I can't seem to find a solution. I have a Spring MVC project and the problem is that I get the error specified in the title in the browser log when I run the app. If I open the index.html in browse (not from Spring) the CSS is loaded.

[This is my structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvTsb.png)

**index.html CSS declaration**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{ /css/index.css }"
          href="../../resources/static/css/index.css">
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("index");

    return model;
}
```

I even tried to add this in the **SecurityConfiguration**

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);

    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/icons/**", "/javascript/**");

}
```

but it doesn't work.

The path is good because as I said when I open the **index.html** in browser the CSS is loaded, I think that the problem is with the **SecurityConfiguration** class, but I don't know what it is.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: From what I searched, Capital letters matter when accesing them this way, maybe in the browser it doesn't matter, can you confirm if maybe that could be?

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast it's not that, still getting the error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574159/refused-to-execute-script-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabled what about this?

Comment: From my search, you need to have an 'static' directory, so you have the permission to access it, this is the most accurate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506091/css-and-java-script-not-rendering-404-error-spring-boot

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast thanks for all the research, in the end, I found the problem and I posted the answer.

Comment: Okay no problem, well done :)

Answer (score 1):

So the error was indeed from **SecurityConfiguration** because I wasn't using the right annotation. The correct one is

```
@EnableWebSecurity
```

and I was using

```
@EnableWebMvc
```

So now my class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll().and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/libraryAppError");
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll();
}
}
```

And everything works fine.