# How to write the path so style.css can reload on my localhost page?

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, frontend

I m trying to create a sidebar where I have a style.css for customize it. When I inspect my page, it seems it never loads and get 404 not found.

```
<head>
<h1>sidebar</h1>
<title>Responsive Sidebar Menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></head>
```

My project is structured like in the following picture:

[image]

I can't figure out how to write the path so it can load properly.

Comment: If your code is in testpage.html, you should use relative path href="./style.css". Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html

Comment: Is it possible to "inspect" the document root folder on your webserver?

Comment: I tried ./style.css before posting and it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your template folder right under resources:

```
src/main/resource/static/css (for CSS files);
src/main/resource/templates (for HTML templates).
Then correct the link tag as follows:

  <link href="../static/css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: i tried just now since my front is built with thymeleaf, but it doenst work...i dont get, if i press ctrl+click it goes to the style file, but when i reload the server and access localhost:8080/testpage, it doenst show the style, and on inspect i can see that the request is 404 on style.css

Comment: any reason it s happening?

Comment: Please read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506091/css-and-java-script-not-rendering-404-error-spring-boot

Comment: <link th:href="@{/static/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" /> this is how looks my include command

Comment: it is in static already , but when i reload the server, it never show on the page

Comment: Zaur thanks, it worked indeed, but i dont get why wouldn t it take the right path...but anyway, it works now

Comment: Please my answer check correct Everybody see that the problem is right